# Excel 2007 how to put a text message in a cell if multiple cells are filled with data

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2007

I am trying to put a text message in a cell (say c1) if multiple cells in column A have data in.  The cells in column A are A1-3, A5, A6 A8 and will have data from 1-5.  I only want the text message to appear if all cells have the data in - ideally an automatic email would be good, but I really am not sure how to do this, so perhaps a text message is easier. Column A will not be filled at the same time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you're trying to do, if I understood your question correctly.  In C1:

```
=IF(OR(ISBLANK(A1),ISBLANK(A2),ISBLANK(A3),ISBLANK(A5),ISBLANK(A6),ISBLANK(A8)),"","This is a message")
```